# Open chromium/chrome with native borders only sometimes?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium, xmonad

I use chromium on my laptop where I (mostly) use [xmonad](http://xmonad.org) as my window manager.

With this the "compact border" option is next to useless and wastes space, so I don't want it. But when I use a non-tiling window manager I do want it to use the compact border, and it gets annoying to have to switch the config option all the time (also it messes up the syncing of options, but that I can disable).

Is there a command-line switch to enable/disable compact borders for only one session? Or any other handy tricks?